# Assigning custom weights to embedding layer in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

Does PyTorch's `nn.Embedding` support manually setting the embedding weights for only specific values?

I know I could set the weights of the entire embedding layer like this -

```
emb_layer = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim)
emb_layer.weights = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.from_numpy(weight_matrix))
```

But does PyTorch provide any succinct/efficient method to set the embedding weights for only one particular value?

Something like `emb_layer.set_weight(5) = torch.tensor([...])` to manually set the embedding only for the value "5"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can run `emb_layer.weight.shape` to see the shape of the weights, and then you can access and change a single weight like this, for example:

```
with torch.no_grad():
  emb_layer.weight[idx_1,idx_2] = some_value
```

I use two indices here since the embedding layer is two dimensional. Some layers, like a Linear layer, would only require one index.